# How Can I Fix My Eclipse Installer & Program?

Tags: installation, java, eclipse

My SSD crashed and I had to restore the OS from a System Image. Much better than having to reinstall Windows but the major hurdle I've had is that Eclipse isn't working.

I already had Eclipse installed but when I tried to run it I got this error message:

[image: Eclipse Error Message]

(*username redacted*)

I've already made sure that Java is installed correctly by checking on Command Prompt. This is the information it provides:

[image: Java Version]

As you can see it's version 1.8 so I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

I made sure to download the Java SE Developement Kit 11.0.2 since at one point it said I was missing the development kit. I'm not sure if it was the same one I had before but it's supposed to be the latest version. Or perhaps I'm supposed to be using a different one? If so it could be causing the issue but I'm not sure.

I decided to reinstall Eclipse to see if that cleared the issue.

I downloaded and tried using eclipse-inst-win64 to reinstall Eclipse but I got redirected to this page: [JRE MISSING](https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/index-handler.php?vm=1_1_7_0_64_0&pn=Eclipse%20Installer&pu=http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer&pi=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/128x128.png)

I was able to find someone who had a similar issue. Perhaps it's the key to fix this. Their issue was posted and resolved on this page: [Eclipse Not Installing](https://www.dezyre.com/questions/5268/eclipse-not-insdtalling-because-i-am-missing-java-for-windows-need-help)

It talks about editing the eclipse.ini file to specify the file path in case that's the issue. Perhaps that's what's causing the above issue? Here's the text inside the eclipse.ini file:

> -startupplugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.200.v20180922-1751.jar--launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.900.v20180922-1751-productorg.eclipse.epp.package.java.product-showsplashorg.eclipse.epp.package.common--launcher.defaultActionopenFile--launcher.defaultActionopenFile--launcher.appendVmargs-vmargs-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace-XX:+UseG1GC-XX:+UseStringDeduplication--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true-Xms256m-Xmx1024m--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM

I really don't see a file path I could edit if that's what could fix the issue otherwise I would have tried it already. Or perhaps I'm looking at the wrong .ini file but I highly doubt that since it's the only eclipse.ini file.

I'm hoping I have provided at least enough information that I can be guided in the right direction.

Update: I was able to get the eclipse-java-2018-12-R-win32-x86_64.zip folder to try to run Eclipse with that but I got the same error message as before.

Update: I've tried moving the eclipse folder into the Programs Folder but I still get the same error message just with a few different file paths:

[image: Eclipse Error 2]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what went wrong now. For some reason the newest JRE isn't working with Eclipse, or at least that's what it seems like. I used ninite.com to install the other two versions of the JRE. Now both Eclipse and the installer work just fine.

I hope this helps for someone else that has the same issue in the future. Hopefully Eclipse is updated to work with the latest JRE, which is 11.0.2, this year.